# Oracle Sql How to calculate if a birthdate is in 2 months from SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I need help making a query that will return results from a table for where all people are currently 25 and whose birthdate is in 2 months (anytime of the month).

My current query is:

```
SELECT * from account_info 
where to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-to_char(birth_date,'YYYY') = 25
AND Months_between(TO_DATE(SYSDATE),TO_DATE(birth_date)) = 2
```

The format of birth_date in the database is `11-NOV-87`

This isn't returning the proper months I need, because this is also calculating the years and it comes out to be 297 months. I was previously using:

```
AND abs(to_char(SYSDATE,'MM')-to_char(birth_date,'MM')) = 2`
```

which showed the proper result but I'm not sure if this will work if the current `SYSDATE = December` and the `birth_date = February`.

How do I return only the people that are currently 25 and where their birthdate is 2 months from the SYSDATE using the proper date calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

`SELECT * from account_info

WHERE to_char(SYSDATE,'YYYY')-to_char(birth_date,'YYYY') = 25
AND to_char(add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), 2),'MM') = to_char(birth_date,'MM');`

The add_months will add 2 to the current sysdate month and compare that value to the birth_date.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WHERE months_between(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),trunc(birth_date,'mm'))=310
```

**EDIT** 
Corrected month count from 298 to 310 (it was calculating 24 turning 25 rather than 25 turning 26).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to only determine the months and not include all the years? I'm attempting to simply put 2 months rather than a large number like 298 (which would need calculating as this batch code is continually run)

Comment: So only consider two months out, without regard to the number of years?  Just change 310 to 2.  But I don't think I understand what you're asking for.  And why is 298 a large number?

Comment: I appreciate your help. Oracle is returning 298 as the months between so I can't simply change the 298 (or 310 in your case) to 2. The second parameter `'mm'` doesn't only pull the month and ignore the years.

Comment: Got it.  Try this: `mod(to_char(sysdate,'mm') + 2,12) = to_char(birth_date,'mm')`

Comment: I like your approach. What happens if the sysdate is October (10) and someone's birthday is in December (12)? mod((10+2), 12) = 0. 0 != 12 in this case. Or does Oracle handle dates differently?